# Why did a migration to https break the communication between the client and the server?

Tags: reactjs, spring, nginx, ssl, https

In a ubuntu server, there is an Nginx webserver that serves a React application.
That application sends HTTP requests to a backend Springboot server (Tomcat) on the same ubuntu machine.

I migrated the webserver to HTTPS, meaning - I activated the SSL and used the certificates. The React app works correctly. [image]

The problem is that the HTTP requests from the app to the Springboot server all fail.
I ran the Springboot server with SSL, and also without. Both the requests don't work.

The server doesn't even return a status code, this is how the Chrom network tools look like:
[image: network tools]
Why changing the client Nginx app to HTTPS affects the server side when the requests should be the same, using HTTP? How can I fix this?

Comment: Since you already have ssl enabled on nginx, you're probably best off using the same instance to do ssl offloading for your tomcat instance (lookup using nginx as tls enabled reverse proxy). The error you're getting is because your react app is trying to hit `http` links. These must all be moved to `https` if the react app itself is served with `https`.

Answer (score 1):

If you moved to HTTPS all calls should be through that.
You can use NGINX to automatically do this.

https://phoenixnap.com/kb/redirect-http-to-https-nginx

https://serversforhackers.com/c/redirect-http-to-https-nginx

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).